# How to parse element with same name at different level in SAX parser java

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I have an xml structure like below

```
<cr:TRFCoraxData instrumentId="8590925624" organizationId="4296241518">
    <cr:Dividends>
        <cr:ExDate>2017-02-27T00:00:00+00:00</cr:ExDate>
        <cr:PeriodEndDate>2017-03-31T00:00:00+00:00</cr:PeriodEndDate>
        <cr:PeriodDuration>P3M</cr:PeriodDuration>
    </cr:Dividends>


    <cr:AdjustmentFactors>
        <cr:ExDate>2222-05-21T00:00:00+00:00</cr:ExDate>
        <cr:AdjustmentFactor>0.50000</cr:AdjustmentFactor>
    </cr:AdjustmentFactors>

    </cr:TRFCoraxData>
```

So i have to element `cr:ExDate` with same name in Kand `AdjustmentFactors` tag.

Now i have pojo classes for both and then i have start and end element tag .

In my end element tag i have below condition like below

```
 if (element.equals("cr:ExDate")) {
            dividend.setExDate(tmpValue);
        }else if (element.equals("cr:DividendEventId")) {
            dividend.setDividendEventId(tmpValue);
        }else if (element.equals("cr:AnnouncementDate")) {
            dividend.setAnnouncementDate(tmpValue);
        }
else if (element.equals("cr:ExDate")) {
            adjustmentFactorObj.setExDate(tmpValue);
        }else if (element.equals("cr:AdjustmentFactor")) {
            adjustmentFactorObj.setAdjustmentFactor(tmpValue);
        }
```

Clearly for "cr:ExDate" element if condition satisfies and i am not able to get and set in adjustmentFactorObj for "cr:ExDate" value.

Please suggest me how can i solve this problem

Comment: I'd suggest switching to StAX, instead of SAX, since keeping track of context is much easier with StAX.

Comment: have you thought of using data binding tools like jibx, castor or jaxb?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
boolean isInDivident;  // it is a field
```

...

```
if (element.equals("cr:Dividends")) {
  isInDivident = true;
} else if ((element.equals("cr:AdjustmentFactors")) {
  isDivident = false;
} else if (element.equals("cr:ExDate") && isInDivident)  {
...
```

Comment: But this booleanType reinitialises every time in the element value

Comment: Dividends / AdjustmentFactors come before ExDate, so when you parser comes to ExDate sInDivident is set to correct value

Answer (score 0):

Writing SAX applications is not easy. Many people are lured into it by the promise of better performance, but you will only get better performance if you are highly skilled in the art. Most people who end up asking questions about SAX on SO probably should be using a different tool for the job. (But you haven't described the task, so we can't judge that.)

In any case, when you use SAX, it's your responsibility to keep track of context. For most situations, a stack holding element names is sufficient: push an element name to the stack in the `startElement` event, pop it in the `endElement event`. That's sufficient in this case to determine, when an `ExDate` arrives, what its parent element is.